# Respond.js (IE8, Bootstrap 3) works on localhost, but not in production

Tags: internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, amazon-cloudfront, respond.js

I've browsed through all other IE8/Respond.js questions here on SO, but no luck so far.

When I test on localhost in IE8 emulator, I get the same error as in production, but Respond works despite that. First we see a broken page for a second, then Bootstrap's grid comes in place and everything is okay. However, in production it stays broken.

The error I get comes from respond-proxy.html file, line 46 (ajax): Permission denied

This is what I got in my base html file:

```
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

{# <!-- Respond.js proxy on external server -->#}
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/respond-proxy.html" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy" />

{# <!-- Respond.js redirect location on local server -->#}
    <link href="{% static "img/respond.proxy.gif" %}" id="respond-redirect" rel="respond-redirect" />

{# <!-- Respond.js proxy script on local server -->#}
    <script src="{% static "js/respond.proxy.js" %}"></script>

<![endif]-->
```

I've tried moving it around (end of head, end of body etc.) but nothing seems to work in production.
We host our static files on S3 (CloudFront). We copied CORS config from here: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/issues/152

I also tried copying the respond-proxy.html into a file hosted along with our static files, but still get the same "Permission denied" error.

Any solutions, workarounds, hints and suggestions are more than welcome.

Edit: I also tried some substitutes like css3-mediaqueries-js, but that didn't work at all.

Comment: Have you tried "locally" (in production) hosting `respond.min.js` instead of using a CDN?

Comment: I replaced `respond.min.js` with a local version and tried it locally. I still get Permission denied (and afterwards it works). Do you have a reason to believe it would work that way if I push it to production since I still have the error locally?

Comment: Really not sure about the error - is it possible the error was possibly due to a cached version of your page still referencing the CDN version, and then trying it again worked by correctly using the local version?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not the cache :-( I checked it, the version is visible. The error might have something to do with CloudFront, but I'm not an expert in that field.

Comment: Ahh ok. Do you have any console access to your S3 instance, to see if it's possible to manually connect to the CDN scripts?

Comment: (Although if it's CloudFront, the error would not be visible locally..)

Comment: We can connect to the scripts, that parts is okay - the Permission denied that we get is from inside the respond-proxy.html, line 46. You can see the code if you copy/paste that url in your browser and view source.

Comment: Any luck @dnmh?  I'm getting same problem.  I pull in CSS from two separate CDNs and also locally.  The bootstrap CDN css appears to come along with local CSS, but the one CSS we have from another CDN gets permission denied.  Does respond-proxy.html need to be at every CDN?  Or can you only have one CDN and have this work?

Comment: Hey Terry, sorry, we had no luck :( At the end, I wrote our own Bootstrap 3 custom CSS that defines specific widths for lower IE browsers.. I make a check for browser version then either include or not include the custom CSS. It's a rather ugly solution, but we couldn't get past CloudFront, or so it seems.